# Scala Bounds Intersection

Tags: scala, types, bounded-types

I have learned about Lower and Upper Bound in Scala.
I know how to deal with them separately but what happens if we take them together i.e. say `A >: B <: C`
My question is based on this problem:

```
trait Thing
class Vehicle extends Thing
class Car extends Vehicle
class Jeep extends Car
class Coupe extends Car
class Motorcycle extends Vehicle
class Bicycle extends Vehicle
class Tricycle extends Bicycle
```

and suppose we declare

```
class Parking[A >: Bicycle <: Vehicle](val plaza: A)
```

So from `A>: Bicycle` we can infer A can have type Bicycle, Vehicle, and Thing
and from `A<: Vehicle` we can infer that A can have any type except Thing

so from above statement can we infer that A can have only types Bicycle, Vehicle, and Thing by using Mathematical Intersection Property?
So I found this working ,according to Liskov's principle

```
new Parking(new Tricycle)
```

but why the following also works?

```
new Parking(new Coupe)
```

I'm new to this, so please guide me rather than marking more duplicate and closing this.

Comment: Maybe just a coincident but wouldn't it make sense you mention the source of your code: https://apiumhub.com/tech-blog-barcelona/scala-type-bounds/ and also that the article already gives the answer to your question?

Comment: No, it doesn't give the answer to the `new Parking(new Coupe)` ?

Comment: @DennisHunziker  `place` has been translated into Spanish `plaza`, so everything is totally different question now O_o?

Answer (score 2):

No, this won't throw an error.

`new Tricycle` can be of types `Tricycle`, `Bicycle`, `Vehicle`, `Thing`, `AnyRef`, `Any`.

`new Parking[Tricycle](new Tricycle)` doesn't compile but `new Parking[Vehicle](new Tricycle)`, `new Parking[Bicycle](new Tricycle)` do.

In `new Parking(new Tricycle)` `A` is inferred to be `Bicycle`, so it doesn't throw an error.

---

`new Coupe` can be of types `Coupe`, `Car`, `Vehicle`, `Thing`, `AnyRef`, `Any`. Among them it's `Vehicle` that solves the inequality `A >: Bicycle <: Vehicle`.

Comment: Please help me with `new Parking(new Coupe)`?

Comment: I understood the case of the Tricycle base on Liskov's Substitution Principle

Comment: Similarly, `A` is inferred to be `Vehicle`.

Comment: `AnyRef` and `Any` will throw an error because of Upper Bound. @Dmytro

Comment: Yes, so what's the question?

Comment: I understood about tricycle case which you told me, I now want to ask about new Parking(new Coupe)

Comment: Sir I'm not able to understand please help me with this in a chat.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171861/discussion-between-animesh-srivastava-and-dmytro-mitin).

Comment: `new Coupe` can be of types `Coupe`, `Car`, `Vehicle`, `Thing`, `AnyRef`, `Any`. Among them it's `Vehicle` that solves the inequality `A >: Bicycle <: Vehicle`.

Comment: Also, I have a small question suppose we have `trait A`, `class B extends A` and `class C extends B`, and suppose I want to apply Liskov Principle on A, so will it work on A and B (the immediate subclass) or also on C? Please guide me

Comment: Both. B is subtype of A, C is subtype of B, C is subtype of A.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle It's about subtyping, not about subclassing (or "immediate" subclassing).

Comment: [There are more types than classes](https://typelevel.org/blog/2017/02/13/more-types-than-classes.html)